# How to Create a Container in docker remote api? (go-dockerclient)

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I am using [go-dockerclient](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) library and i want to create container using the [CreateContainer](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Client.CreateContainer) go-dockerclient method but where should I pass the docker image id 
I created this function

```
func CreateContainer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

    client,err:=docker.NewTLSClient(Endpoint,Cert,Key,Ca)
    if err!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    container,er:=client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{Name:"cont"})
    if er!=nil{
        panic(err)
    }

 }
```

for example if i have a given image id where should I add it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the image in the Config struct:

```
 container, err := client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{
    Name: "container name",
    Config: &docker.Config{
      Image: "ubuntu:latest",
    },
 })
```

Comment: thank you but do you know how can I run it in background that is docker run -d ubuntu:latest (with the -d flag)

Comment: You can start the container with
`docker.StartContainer(container.ID, &docker.HostConfig{})`